# Python3: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a text-based game, and I'm trying to return two separate values from a function, specifically this chunk of the function:

```
if userhp > 0 and enemyhp <= 0:
    print(enemyname + ' has been defeated!')
    lootdrop = loot_generator()
    print(lootdrop)
    restart = input('Restart? Y/N ')
    if restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
        while restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
            restart = input('Invalid input. Restart? Y/N ')
    return(restart, lootdrop)
```

This is the chunk that I get the error from:

```
else:
    userhp = default_userhp
    damagebuff = default_damagebuff
    restart, lootdrop = normal_ai(userhp, damagebuff) # <-- **error here**
    if lootdrop == '0':
    damagebuff += 1
    elif lootdrop == '1':
        default_userhp += 2
    if restart.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        ...
```

By request of a commenter, here is the entire normal_ai function (Don't know why the whitespacing after defining it is missing, but it's there in the normal code):

```
def normal_ai(playerhp, damagebuff):

enemyname = all_enemy_names[random.randint(0,2)]
enemyhp = random.randint(5,13)
userhp = playerhp
iselite = 0

if enemyhp in [11, 12, 13]:
    enemyname = 'Elite ' + enemyname
elif enemyhp == 5:
    enemyname = 'Weakling ' + enemyname

while enemyhp > 0 and userhp > 0:
    userdmg = random.randint(0,5) + damagebuff
    damage = random.randint(0,2)
    if iselite == 1:
        hitchance = random.randint(0,1)
        if hitchance == 1:
            damage += 1
    if True:
        print('')
        if damage == 0:
            print(enemyname + ' missed.')
        else:
            print(enemyname + ' strikes you for ' + str(damage) + ' HP!')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            userhp -= damage
            print('You have ' + str(userhp) + ' HP left.')
        print('')
        action = input('ATTACK or FLEE? ')
        if action.lower() not in ['attack', 'flee']:
            while action.lower() not in ['attack', 'flee', 'wait']:
                action = input('Invalid input. ATTACK or FLEE? ')
        if action.lower() == 'attack':
            enemyhp -= userdmg
            print('You do ' + str(userdmg) + ' to the ' + enemyname +'!')
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(enemyname + ' has ' + str(enemyhp) + ' HP left.')
        elif action.lower() == 'flee':
            fleechance = random.randint(0,3)
            if fleechance == 0:
                print('You fail to escape!')
                time.sleep(0.5)
            elif userhp <= 0:
                print('You are too wounded to run!')
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                print('You successfully escape!')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                break #END
        elif action.lower() == 'wait':
            print('You wait to see the ' + enemyname + "'s next move.")
            time.sleep(0.5)

if userhp > 0 and enemyhp <= 0:
    print(enemyname + ' has been defeated!')
    loot_generator()
    restart = input('Restart? Y/N ')
    if restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
        while restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
            restart = input('Invalid input. Restart? Y/N ')
    return(restart)
elif userhp <= 0 and enemyhp > 0:
    print('You have been struck down by ' + enemyname + '!')
    restart = input('Restart? Y/N ')
    if restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
        while restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
            restart = input('Invalid input. Restart? Y/N ')
    return(restart)
else:
    print('Somehow... You both killed eachother!')
    restart = input('Restart? Y/N ')
    if restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
        while restart.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:
            restart = input('Invalid input. Restart? Y/N ')
    return(restart)
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Can you show the full function `normal_ai`?

Comment: @TomDalton Sorry for the slow response. Added it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

If your first if condition `if userhp > 0 and enemyhp <= 0:` evaluates to false then your function will return `None` which is not a 2-tuple hence it cannot be unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are doing something like this:

```
foo, bar = some_function()
```

... but `some_function()` is only returning one item. "... need more than one item to unpack" means that the unpacking (splitting the results to two or more variables) only "unpacked" one item.

In your case that means that `normal_ai(...)` is probably not returning what you think it's returning. A simple print statement can help validate your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `normal_ai`, the error can be replicated as such:

```
def foo(one,two):
    return one,

a,b = foo('bar','baz')
```

The previous can cause this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    a,b = foo('bar','baz') ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score -1):

If the return statement is `normal_ai` is `return(restart, lootdrop)` then by this statement, you are returning a tuple [one value]. Omit the parenthesis in the return statement.

Comment: Wouldn't make the slightest difference. It would still be a `tuple`. That's what gets unpacked.